# Obtain tango device main camera image in unity

Tags: camera, unity-game-engine, google-project-tango, tango

In my project I am capturing point cloud and based on that I create a binary mask, which I want to apply to captured image from Tango tablet main camera, so that the final image is a cutout of the detected points of point cloud.

I tried to use the tango examples for getting the camera image so that further postprocessing can be made, but I had no success. (temporary hack includes a camera to render texture and then applying a masking shader to the render)

What is the easiest method to obtain the tango main camera image in a Unity?

Comment: check my reply in this question, it might be helpful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41176053/post-processing-effects-with-tango-camera

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `VideoOverlayProvider.cs` file, there are two static methods SetCallback(..) which sound like what you are looking for:

```
    /// Connect a callback to a camera for access to the pixels.
    /// 
    /// This is not recommended for display but for applications requiring access to the
    /// <code>HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_YV12</code> pixel data.  The camera is selected via TangoCameraId.  Currently only 
    /// <code>TANGO_CAMERA_COLOR</code> and <code>TANGO_CAMERA_FISHEYE</code> are supported.
    /// 
    /// The <i>onImageAvailable</i> callback will be called when a new frame is available from the camera. The
    /// Enable Video Overlay option must be enabled for this to succeed.
    ///
    /// Note: The first scan-line of the color image is reserved for metadata instead of image pixels.
```

You can get access to both the TANGO_CAMERA_COLOR camera and the TANGO_CAMERA_FISHEYE camera frames